# How to make an object cast shadows on other things but not itself? (Eevee)

Tags: materials, shaders

I'm trying to make a low-poly model, and it looks very weird with casting shadows on itself. I'm trying to have it essentially only use vertex shading, not cast shadows, on itself. However, I still want it to cast shadows on other objects. Is this possible?

Here is what I mean. This is with shadow mode set to "opaque":

[image]

However, when set to "None", it looks much better for what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

But I want to keep shadows cast onto other objects, which is only the case with shadows not set to "None"

[image]

I hope this makes sense and is possible!

Comment: I suppose disabling shadow ray visibility on this object eliminates its own cast shadow as well, or no?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/object_settings/object_data.html

Comment: I might try having two objects with linked mesh data, one invisible/transparent for shadow casting, the other visible with shadow casting disabled.

Comment: @AllenSimpson I don't know where to find this setting in Eevee, if it even exists. I can't use Cycles.

Comment: @TheLabCat Just tried it, it made the non transparent mesh completely black as the shadow-casting version just blocked all the light I suppose.

Comment: @SmallFlameBoi my apologies, better for someone else to answer this - I am very cycles-centric

Comment: You could duplicate your object and give it another material that will make it transparent but with a shadow on athor objects, a bit tedious though

Comment: @moonboots No, as I said in reply to another comment with that suggestion that makes the model turn completely black (the visible one, because the invisible one will cast complete shadow on the visible model)

Comment: oh you're right  ;)

Comment: Can you render the scene + the cat and then only the cat without shadows and combine them?